# :javap -p <classname> returns IlegalArgumentException

Tags: scala

Getting below error in Scala REPL

```
scala> :javap -p Add
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:264)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JavapClass$JavapTool$.apply(JavapClass.scala:337)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JavapClass.tool$lzycompute(JavapClass.scala:37)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JavapClass.tool(JavapClass.scala:37)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JavapClass.apply(JavapClass.scala:49)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.javapCommand(ILoop.scala:332)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$standardCommands$6(ILoop.scala:187)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands$LineCmd.apply(LoopCommands.scala:132)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands.colonCommand(LoopCommands.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands.colonCommand$(LoopCommands.scala:101)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.colonCommand(ILoop.scala:44)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:696)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:416)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:437)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$process$1(ILoop.scala:1012)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:75)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:88)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:99)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:104)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

That entry seems to have slain the compiler.  Shall I replay
your session? I can re-run each line except the last one.
[y/n]
Abandoning crashed session.
```

Please share if anyone encountered this issue & able to resolve. Below is the versions information. Thanks in advance!

```
C:\Users\email>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.2 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

C:\Users\email>java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Sorry missed giving another piece of code. Just trying to create a class "Add" in scala REPL and javap not working.                                         
scala> class Add(i:Int,j:Int)
defined class Add

Comment: Unable to recreate the problem (same Scala/Java versions).

Comment: Ok thanks for checking. Must be something to do with my system. Will try from another laptop.

Comment: @MohanRayapuvari have you figured out how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As the answer  said [Why does installing Scala require additionally installing JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684005/why-does-installing-scala-require-additionally-installing-jdk)

**Maybe you just installed Jre not  JDK.**

To solve the problem, install the corresponding version  JDK.

`:javap` command within Scala REPL invoke the `javap` tool installed by JAVA SDK via `java.util.spi.ToolProvider`[ver2.13.1]. Jre don't include those JDK tools such as `javap, jdb, jar`.